# Flutter exit callback handler in all cases cross-platform

Tags: flutter, dart, sigterm

I am looking for a way to dispose some final things before my application closes. I want this to happen on web close, on native window close and on mobile close.

I thought I'd do it like this, but the flutter engines takes my widgets and ends the main function.

```dart
void main() {
  try {
    runApp(MyApp());
  }
  finally {
    customDisposeFunction(); // TODO: Oh no, this function is called right away!
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
}
```

I have also tried to use [flutter_window_close](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_window_close), but that does not dispose when I press the stop button in visual studio code.

I have also tried to watch via [ProcessSignal](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.5/dart-io/ProcessSignal/watch.html), but that is not cross-platform at all.

I have also tried to make the app a `StatefulWidget`, but `dispose` in the `State` is not called (on windows) when closing down the window.

Are there some good ways to handle this cross-platform?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because finally will get a hit directly after you write it this way.
Instead you should try to write it in dispose method of your main class (you have to make it Stateful though)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `MyApp` a `StatefulWidget` and override its `dispose()` method.

Comment: I tried this, but `dispose` is not called when exiting the application (in windows for sure)

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that. Scratch that idea.